# read from memory WordprocessingDocument and save to AddAlternativeFormatImportPart using OpenXml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, docx

this work fine:

```
MemoryStream ms = //do some in memory on WordprocessingDocument ;
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML,
                    altChunkId);  
using(var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\temp\\1.docx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.Read))
        ms.WriteTo(fs);

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\temp\\1.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        chunk.FeedData(fs);
```

can't correct read from memory stream WordprocessingDocument and save to AddAlternativeFormatImportPart on another using OpenXml without save to disc

```
MemoryStream ms = //do some in memory on WordprocessingDocument ;
chunk.FeedData(fs);
```

how it do?

it's help me

```
MemoryStream ms = //do some in memory on WordprocessingDocument ;
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
chunk.FeedData(ms);
```

Comment: Did you set the position of your memory stream to the begin of the stream?